# Creating a wordcloud with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, word-cloud

Im trying to create a [wordcloud](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a5/TagCloudCloud.png/800px-TagCloudCloud.png) with Matplotlib.  Essentially I am able to put text at arbitrary locations in my grid, but need to work out a way of preventing them from colliding.  In relation to this I am stuck on two questions:

1. What is the unit of fontsize?
2. How do I transfer the "fontsize" of the text to units in my figure, so I can mark them as used?  That is, how do I know how much space each letter will take up in my grid?  Ideally I would not have to mark out a whole rectangle around each word, but only the pixels they actually use as available for other words.

Comment: 1. [points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)). 2. render them first?  The bounding-box algorithm will end up being much simpler to implement.  Otherwise you need to know the resulting vectors of the glyphs and at that point I think you don't even want matplotlib so much as a 2d library itself (pycairo, e.g.)

Comment: why it supposed to be with matplotlib at all?

Comment: It doesn't have to be matplotlib, but I'm using a conceptually easy idea (essentially; pick places in a grid that are closest to the center but still fits the word) but shows to be hard to implement.  Often I feel this  way with plotting, easy to understand what you want, hard to get it done.  In this case I wan to learn how the "pt"-measure in _fontsize_ translates to pixels in my images. I think I would learn a lot about plotting from seeing how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how to do it with matplotlib but I have used this in the past: http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/a-wordcloud-in-python.html